# With Ant, how do I create seperate jar files from one src directory?

Tags: java, blackberry, ant

I have one source directory in which I am trying to create separate cod files since my resources (PNG files) are beyond the limit imposed by the RAPC compiler.

I am trying to create:

1. .cod(s) for the source
2. .cod(s) for low res. resources
3. .cod(s) for hi res. resources

Which I am successful in creating the following:

AppMeasurement_BlackBerry.cod

com_mch_coffeehouse-1.cod

com_mch_coffeehouse.cod

com_mch_coffeehouse.jad

com_mch_coffeehouse_resources_hires-1.cod

com_mch_coffeehouse_resources_hires-2.cod

com_mch_coffeehouse_resources_hires-3.cod

com_mch_coffeehouse_resources_hires-4.cod

com_mch_coffeehouse_resources_hires-5.cod

com_mch_coffeehouse_resources_hires-6.cod

com_mch_coffeehouse_resources_hires-7.cod

com_mch_coffeehouse_resources_hires.cod

com_mch_coffeehouse_resources_lowres-1.cod

com_mch_coffeehouse_resources_lowres-2.cod

com_mch_coffeehouse_resources_lowres-3.cod

com_mch_coffeehouse_resources_lowres-4.cod

com_mch_coffeehouse_resources_lowres.cod

common-1.cod

common.cod

However, the application does not start-up and from the event log on the device, I get that wonderful encrypted message:

RIM Wireless Handheld Java Loader
Copyright 2001-2009 Research In Motion Limited
Connected
guid:0x97C9F5F641D25E5F time: Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969  severity:0 type:2 app:System data:JVM:INFOp=23575346,a='5.0.0.979',o='5.1.0.177',h=4001507
guid:0x9C3CD62E3320B498 time: Fri Jul 01 16:59:26 2011  severity:1 type:3 app:Java Exception data:
        Error
        No detail message
        com_mch_coffeehouse(4E0E2E1F)
         CoffeeHouseClient
         
         0x3764
        com_mch_coffeehouse(4E0E2E1F)
         CoffeeHouseClient
         main
         0x30BD
guid:0x0 time: Fri Jul 01 16:59:26 2011  severity:2 type:3 app: data:
        Traceback:

guid:0x97C9F5F641D25E5F time: Fri Jul 01 16:59:31 2011  severity:0 type:2 app:System data:JVM:INFOp=23575346,a='5.0.0.979',o='5.1.0.177',h=4001507

Anyway, any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated before this becomes a critical blocker - yippee!

My Ant script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<property name="package.label" value="com_mch_coffeehouse" />

<property name="lowres.label" value="com_mch_coffeehouse_resources_lowres" />

<property name="hires.label" value="com_mch_coffeehouse_resources_hires" />

<property name="jde.home" value="C:\Eclipse3.6\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components" />

<property name="workspace" value="C:\Users\jtp\Documents\mch" />

<property name="appmeasure" value="${workspace}\AppMeasurement_BlackBerry\deliverables\Standard\5.0.0" />

<property name="common" value="${workspace}\Common-BlackBerry\deliverables\Standard\5.0.0" />

<property name="simulator" value="${jde.home}\simulator" />

<property name="bin" value="${jde.home}\bin" />

<property name="src" value="src" />

<property name="respackage" value="${src}\com\mch\coffee_house\res" />

<property name="hi" value="${respackage}\hi" />

<property name="low" value="${respackage}\low" />

<property name="dest" value="deliverables" />

<property name="ota.dir" value="${dest}\ota" />

<target name="debug" depends="ota" description="Build, deploy project and Launches Remote Debug Server">
    <exec executable="cmd.exe" dir="${bin}" spawn="true">
        <arg value="/c" />
        <arg value="jdwp.bat" />
    </exec>
</target>

<target name="simulate" depends="ota" description="Build, deploy project and Launches Simulator">
    <exec executable="cmd.exe" dir="${simulator}" spawn="true">
        <arg value="/c" />
        <arg value="${simulator}\9700.bat" />
    </exec>
</target>

<target name="ota" depends="build" description="Build OTA project.">
    <mkdir dir="${ota.dir}" />
    <jadtool input="${dest}\${package.label}.jad" destdir="${ota.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${appmeasure}" includes="*.cod" />
        <fileset dir="${common}" includes="*.cod" />
        <fileset dir="${dest}" includes="*.cod" />
    </jadtool>
</target>

<target name="deploy" depends="build" description="Build and deploy project.">
    <copy todir="${simulator}" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir="${appmeasure}">
            <include name="*.cod" />
            <include name="*.debug" />
            <include name="*.csl" />
            <include name="*.cso" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${simulator}" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir="${common}">
            <include name="*.cod" />
            <include name="*.debug" />
            <include name="*.csl" />
            <include name="*.cso" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${simulator}" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir="${dest}">
            <include name="*.cod" />
            <include name="*.debug" />
            <include name="*.csl" />
            <include name="*.cso" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="build" depends="buildhiresources" description="Builds project.">
    <!-- Copy the resource package to be compiled with preserved folder hierarchy -->
    <!--<copy todir="${dest}">
        <fileset dir="${src}">
            <include name="com/mch/coffee_house/res/low/*.png" />
            <include name="com/mch/coffee_house/res/hi/*.png" />
            <exclude name="**/*.java" />
            <exclude name="com/mch/coffee_house/res/torch/*.png" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>-->
    <!--
    ${appmeasure}\AppMeasurement_BlackBerry.jar:${common}\danicacommon.jar:${dest}\com_mch_coffeehouse_resources_hires.jar:${dest}\com_mch_coffeehouse_resources_lowres.jar
    -->
    <rapc jdehome="${jde.home}" jdkhome="${java.home}" import="${appmeasure}\AppMeasurement_BlackBerry.jar:${common}\danicacommon.jar:${dest}\com_mch_coffeehouse_resources_hires.jar:${dest}\com_mch_coffeehouse_resources_lowres.jar" destdir="${dest}" noconvert="false" output="${package.label}" quiet="true" verbose="false" generatesourcelist="false" nopreverify="true">
        <jdp type="cldc" title="mch coffeehouse" vendor="MCH Inc" version="1.0.0" description="Find a coffee house from your BlackBerry device." arguments="" systemmodule="false" runonstartup="false" startuptier="7" ribbonposition="0" nameresourcebundle="com.mch.coffeehouse" nameresourceid="0" icon="../src/com/mch/coffee_house/res/hi/icon.png">
        </jdp>
        <src>
            <fileset dir=".">
                <exclude name="src/com/mch/coffee_house/res/hi/*.java*" />
                <exclude name="src/com/mch/coffee_house/res/low/*.java*" />
                <include name="src/**/*.java*" />
                <include name="src/**/*.rrc*" />
                <include name="src/**/*.rrh*" />
                <include name="src/**/*.cod*" />
                <include name="src/**/*.cso*" />
                <include name="src/**/*.MF*" />
                <!-- Add the preserved folder hierachy to be compiled as is -->
                <!--<include name="${dest}/com/**/*.*" />-->
            </fileset>
        </src>
    </rapc>
    <sigtool jdehome="${jde.home}" password="########" close="false">
        <fileset dir="${dest}" includes="*.cod" />
    </sigtool>
</target>
<!-- Hi Res. Resources -->
<target name="buildhiresources" depends="buildlowresources" description="Builds low resolution resources project.">
    <!-- Copy the resource package to be compiled with preserved folder hierarchy -->
    <copy todir="${dest}">
        <fileset dir="${src}">
            <include name="com/mch/coffee_house/res/hi/*.png" />
            <exclude name="com/mch/coffee_house/res/low/*.png" />
            <exclude name="**/*.java" />
            <exclude name="com/mch/coffee_house/res/torch/*.png" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <rapc jdehome="${jde.home}" jdkhome="${java.home}" destdir="${dest}" noconvert="false" output="${hires.label}" quiet="true" verbose="false" generatesourcelist="false" nopreverify="true">
        <jdp type="library" title="MCH Library" vendor="MCH Inc" version="1.0.0" description="coffeehouse hi-res resources library.">
        </jdp>
        <src>
            <fileset dir=".">
                <!-- Add the preserved folder hierachy to be compiled as is -->
                <include name="src/com/mch/coffee_house/res/hi/*.java*" />
                <include name="${dest}/com/**/*.*" />
                <exclude name="${dest}/com/mch/coffee_house/res/low/*.png" />
            </fileset>
        </src>
    </rapc>
    <sigtool jdehome="${jde.home}" password="########" close="false">
        <fileset dir="${dest}" includes="*.cod" />
    </sigtool>
</target>
<!-- Low Res. Resources -->
<target name="buildlowresources" description="Builds low resolution resources project.">
    <!-- Copy the resource package to be compiled with preserved folder hierarchy -->
    <copy todir="${dest}">
        <fileset dir="${src}">
            <exclude name="com/mch/coffee_house/res/hi/*.png" />
            <include name="com/mch/coffee_house/res/low/*.png" />
            <exclude name="**/*.java" />
            <exclude name="com/mch/coffee_house/res/torch/*.png" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <rapc jdehome="${jde.home}" jdkhome="${java.home}" destdir="${dest}" noconvert="false" output="${lowres.label}" quiet="true" verbose="false" generatesourcelist="false" nopreverify="true">
        <jdp type="library" title="MCH Library" vendor="MCH Inc" version="1.0.0" description="coffeehouse low-res resources library.">
        </jdp>
        <src>
            <fileset dir=".">
                <!-- Add the preserved folder hierachy to be compiled as is -->
                <include name="src/com/mch/coffee_house/res/low/*.java*" />
                <include name="${dest}/com/**/*.*" />
            </fileset>
        </src>
    </rapc>
    <sigtool jdehome="${jde.home}" password="########" close="false">
        <fileset dir="${dest}" includes="*.cod" />
    </sigtool>
</target>

<target name="clean" description="Clean the destination directory.">
    <delete dir="${ota.dir}" failonerror="no" />
    <delete dir="${dest}" failonerror="no" />
    <mkdir dir="${dest}" />
</target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [BlackBerry Ant Tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/) and [Preprocessor](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/docs#preproc) to generate separate folders with source files and resources and [compile them](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/docs#rapc) to separate application files.